# Native or Sino Japanese numbers?

Tags: numbers

When listing steps (step 1, 2, 3, etc) do you use the Native Japanese counter or the Sino Japanese counter?

Comment: What kind of steps?

Answer (score 1):

Sino-Japanese.

ステップ[1]{いち}、ステップ[2]{に}、ステップ[3]{さん}。